# SYS.DBMS_DEBUG_JDWP", ligne 68 ORA-06512: à ligne 1?

Tags: sql, oracle, debugging, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Exécution du PL/SQL : CALL DBMS_DEBUG_JDWP.CONNECT_TCP( '192.168.1.28', '4000' )
ORA-24247: accès réseau refusé par la liste de contrôle d'accès (ACL)
ORA-06512: à "SYS.DBMS_DEBUG_JDWP", ligne 68
ORA-06512: à ligne 1

I would like to run in debug mode

Answer (score 2):

You can do one of two things:

1- Sort the ACL properly such that the database is allowed to talk to your machine on the debugger PORT(s)

```
BEGIN
 DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.APPEND_HOST_ACE
 (
 host => '192.168.0.10',
 lower_port => null,
 upper_port => null,
 ace => xs$ace_type(privilege_list => xs$name_list('jdwp'),
 principal_name => 'scott',
 principal_type => xs_acl.ptype_db)
 );
END;
```

2- Switch SQL Developer to use DBMS_DEBUG instead.

[image]

Comment: I would like to use this mode to see the contents of the TYPE and RECORD (COLLECTION) variables

Comment: Can you help me for the first solution?

Comment: refresh, i included a code sample for ACL. You'll need your machine's IP address where sql developer is running (and one that the database server can reach) and your oracle database USER name that you are using for the debug connection